# How to force case-sensitive column in Sqlite3 with Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I tried to find solution but usually people writes about this in terms of string comparing, not the properties of column.
I have column with artists names, problem is column is case insensitive resulting in duplicate entry eg. "Depeche Mode" and "depeche mode" are two different records.

My Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('artists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
        });
    }
```

In code I'm trying to inserting artists in the loop using

```
$n_ar = \App\Artist::firstOrNew(['name'=>$artists[$i]]);
$n_ar->save();
```

I am using Sqlite3. Laravel documentation is unfortunately silent in terms of column modifiers like COLLATE and NOCASE in migrations.

Comment: Seems like [COLLATE](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3666#issuecomment-159188191) is available for migrations. [Also](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3666#issuecomment-336092073).

Comment: By the way, you can make SQL query in RAW. Might be not so pretty like `firstOrNew()`, but you can use those indicies.

Comment: This proposal is for mySQL  but my question is for SQLITE3